# Join Core Data objects using a computed value

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-data

In order to 'protect' some data I would like to use a computed key to link two Core Data objects on iOS devices.

By passing several values from object 'source' to myObstufacte(...) method a key value is returned which is used to select a row in the target object. The data would be imported from an XML file in batches of 1000+ source & target pairings which would be read-only once loaded.

I am new to the joys of Core Data although not to ORMs such as Hibernate which let you drop down to native SQL to handle this kind of requirement.

How can I do this using Core Data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a predicate (NSPredicate) that specifies whatever criteria you want, and then add that to a fetch request (NSFetchRequest). Execute the fetch request to retrieve the objects you want.